# How to implement the Keep Alive mechanism for long running WCF Service requests?

Tags: c#, wcf, http, iis-7.5, firewall

Recently, we migrated one of our existing web service to WCF service with basic http binding (hosted in IIS). The problem is whenever user sending a long running request (>5min) to the service, the client keep on waiting for server response until closing it manually. After analysing the Wireshark and Firewall logs we found the reason, the default HTTP session timeout set for 300 sec in firewall due to this firewall remove the long running session from the table after 5min.

We can resolve this by increasing HTTP session timeout in firewall but the complexity is we can control it at server side firewall but we can’t control at client side(each client will have different ISP and IT Policy). So my network admin suggested to implement the keep-alive mechanism (sending heart beat message to server) but it doesn’t worked for me.

I tried following things while implementing keep-alive mechanism,

- First, I tried to send echo messages to server with the same channel
  which created for long running request but it was failed since the
  channel already waiting for response.
- Then I tried to send echo message to server for every four min with
  separate channel but there is not impact on the issue since it using
  the brand new connections.
- I tried with async service calling pattern but there is no impact.
- Finally, I tried by adding the Keep-Alive (Keep-Alive: max=100,
  timeout=1801) header for each request and response at both client and
  server side again there is no impact on the issue.

So, could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: You better make two requests. One to submit the request, that goes into a queue and returns some unique ticket. A second request retrieves the result based on the ticket returned by the first call. Much better scalable and doesn't have timeout issues.

Comment: Thanks Rene! I already started to implementing the same solution. Out of curiosity I want to know is there any other possibilities to resolve this.

Comment: If you control every single network component (modems, routers, switches, firewalls) for every possible network route between your server and the client you can instruct them to set their timeouts to 10 minutes.... but that is only a theoretical option... so in practice: No. Just keep in mind that http is meant for request/response type of exchanges that are reasonable small and short-lived.